# Angulartics - $analytics.eventTrack not firing ga events

Tags: angularjs, google-analytics, google-tag-manager, angulartics

I am trying to track an event on a tag of a drop-down menu. If I use `analytics-on` in the html directly I am only able to track the click event and not the `onchange` event.

To work around this, I have a function attached to an `ng-change` like so: `<select ng-change=“sortListView( )”>` and a controller based on the documentation:

```
controller: function($scope, $analytics){ 
  $scope.sortListView = function() { 
    […] 
    $analytics.eventTrack('testTag'); 
  }; 
}
```

However, the event is not getting picked up by google analytics. Is there any additional implementation required for this to work in my angular app? I've added the scripts and injected `angulartics`, `angulartics.google.analytics` dependencies based on the documentation. Declarative event tracking works without a problem, only having issues with `$analytics`.

Comment: How are you verifying that the event doesn't get picked up? Are you checking in Real-time or with GA Debugger or Console... or ...?

Comment: If you are using `google-tag-manager` you only have to include the `angulartics` & `angulartics.google.tagmanager` module and the library

Comment: @nyuen Yes, I'm using the console/ObservePoint to see if events are getting picked up. I did `console.log(typeof $analytics)` in the sortListView function and it logged `object` to the console when an item in the drop-down menu is selected. Do I need to inject `$analytics` in my module config? Right now I have $analyticsProvider configured as`$analyticsProvider.firstPageview(true);` and `$analyticsProvider.withAutoBase(true);`

Comment: @IsraGab I have all three included: `angulartics`, `angulartics.google.tagmanager`, and `angulartics.google.analytics`